# Significance behind splitting of (x+y)^7-(x^7+y^7)?

Tags: factorization, symmetric-polynomials

A quick check via third roots of unity establishes$$(x+y)^7-(x^7+y^7) = 7xy(x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2)^2$$
Some questions:

- What is the significance of this factorization?
- Does it have any connection to the Klein quartic?
- Are there analogues for other exponents or dimensions?

Comment: Can you tell us why you'd expect that there is a connection with Klein's quartic and/or what sort of significance this factorization might have?

Comment: If I could give you a concrete answer to either of your questions, then I wouldn't have asked them myself...

Comment: There are lots and lots of polynomials which factorize: why do you expect yours to be connected to any specific well-known curve? One could ask countably many such questions!

Comment: @viv: in that case, then the question seems too broad in its present form, see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/203/frequently-asked-questions-for-mathoverflow

Comment: I've run across this before (and am sure others have too).
I don't remember a direct connection with the Klein quartic, but
it does bear on the Fermat septic.
It's easier to understand if written symmetrically in terms of
$x,y,z$ with $x+y+z=0$.  In general, the intersection of
the Fermat curve $x^n+y^n+z^n=0$ with the line $x+y+z=0$
is invariant under coordinate permutations.  It contains
the three points $(0:1:-1)$,  $(-1:0:1)$, $(1:-1:0)$
if $n$ is odd, and the points $(1:\omega:\omega^2)$ with
$\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ with multiplicity $0,2,1$ for 
$n\equiv 0,1,2 \bmod 3$.  [cont'd ...]

Comment: [... due to 600-character limit]
and $n=7$ is the last case where this accounts for all
$n$ points of intersection with multiplicity.  If I remember right
the sum of the points $(1:\omega:\omega^2)$ is used to show
that for prime $p>7$ the Jacobian of the Fermat curve of degree $p$
has positive rank.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Noam Elkies, this was the type of response I was hoping for. Apologies if the question was too vaguely worded for some. In my mind, it has been answered now.